# How can I let someone view and edit specific databases in MySQL

Tags: mysql

"How can I let someone view and edit specific databases in MySQL"

I ask this question to my web hosting company then they said "You need to give cPanel ID and password for him to edit your databases

I feel so insecure in giving full access of cPanel
I just want to add an user ID and password into specific databases then I'll give them for him to access

In cPanel it's easy to create a FTP user for someone to access specific folders.
Isn't there any way to do it like FTP?

Comment: By creating the user in MySQL and giving them the appropriate grants on databases/tables.

Comment: No. You can't use DB through FTP. FTP gives access to files, but even if you get to MySQL files, you won't be able to edit them.
In order to edit the DB you need either remote access (hard to setup and mainetain); or use web applications like phpMyAdmin.

Comment: But this won't let you do anything until you have access to the database (direct or via any external tool - maybe PHPMyAdmin).

Answer (score 0):

If you can upload scripts to the server (I assume you can) you can always install standalone instance of PhpMyAdmin, and configure this instance to only access specific server/databases. Moreover - creating custom login and password allows you to grant access only to specific database/tables etc.